# Input box events like onfocus, onblur, onkeypress are not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML,

`<input id="searchval" type="text" class="search-query" value="People, Links" onfocus = "searchtext();" onblur = "searchetextin();" onkeypress = "Searchinput();" placeholder="People, Links">`

This is the search text on my site and when user presses enter key I'll trigger the agent to print the search results.

onkeypress event is used for searching results in database and printing them. But it is not working in Chrome. Results are printing well on FF and IE.

As I press Enter key, it browser only flashes and nothing happens. Interestingly, it doesnt execute alert("1");

Searchinput() code :-

```
function Searchinput() {
    alert("1");
    document.getElementById('searchval').onkeypress = function(e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;       
        if ( e.keyCode == '13' ) {
           var search = document.getElementById("searchval").value;
           //alert(window.parent.frames.length);
           if ( search == "" ) {
           alert("Search field can not be blank");
           return false;
           }
           if ( window.parent.frames.length == 3 ) {
           var user = document.forms[0].UserName.value;
           parent.frames[2].location = "aSearchResults?OpenAgent&" + search +"~"+user;
           return false;
           } else {
           var user = document.forms[0].UserName.value;
           parent.frames[1].location = "aSearchResults?OpenAgent&" + search+"~"+user;
           return false;
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Please help....

Comment: Have you checked the console in developer tools of chrome for errors

Comment: There are no errors I checked it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why and how but the function works if you define it as variable

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="searchval" type="text" class="search-query" 
         onkeypress="Searchinput();" placeholder="People, Links">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Searchinput = function() {
            alert("1");
            document.getElementById('searchval').onkeypress = function (e) {
                if (!e) e = window.event;
                if (e.keyCode == '13') {
                    var search = document.getElementById("searchval").value;
                    //alert(window.parent.frames.length);
                    if (search == "") {
                        alert("Search field can not be blank");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (window.parent.frames.length == 3) {
                        var user = document.forms[0].UserName.value;
                        parent.frames[2].location = "aSearchResults?OpenAgent&" + search + "~" + user;
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        var user = document.forms[0].UserName.value;
                        parent.frames[1].location = "aSearchResults?OpenAgent&" + search + "~" + user;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited a little of your code(removed the call to functions whose definition you haven't shared)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="searchval" type="text" class="search-query" value="People, Links" 
         onkeypress="Searchinput();" placeholder="People, Links">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Searchinput() {
            alert("1");
            document.getElementById('searchval').onkeypress = function (e) {
                if (!e) e = window.event;
                if (e.keyCode == '13') {
                    var search = document.getElementById("searchval").value;
                    //alert(window.parent.frames.length);
                    if (search == "") {
                        alert("Search field can not be blank");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (window.parent.frames.length == 3) {
                        var user = document.forms[0].UserName.value;
                        parent.frames[2].location = "aSearchResults?OpenAgent&" + search + "~" + user;
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        var user = document.forms[0].UserName.value;
                        parent.frames[1].location = "aSearchResults?OpenAgent&" + search + "~" + user;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On pressing a key for the very first time, the alert happens and it then override the event handler with the handler you have mentioned in Searchinput(), thus the next time you perform a key press, the alert don't happen.
Does this makes sense?